# PHP-5.6 compile tokenizer error Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: php, ubuntu, compilation, compiler-errors

I'm setup my new notebook with **multiple PHP versions** (7 and 5.6), when after compile PHP-7.0 perfectly I get **tokenizer** error in PHP-5.6 compile process.

### Steps

- `sudo mkdir /opt/source`
- `cd /opt/source`
- `sudo git clone https://github.com/php/php-src.git`
- `cd php-src`
- `sudo git checkout PHP-5.6.17`
- `sudo ./configure 
  --prefix=/opt/php-5.6 
  --with-pdo-pgsql 
  --with-zlib-dir 
  --with-freetype-dir 
  --enable-mbstring 
  --with-libxml-dir=/usr 
  --enable-soap 
  --enable-calendar 
  --with-curl 
  --with-mcrypt 
  --with-zlib 
  --with-gd 
  --with-pgsql 
  --disable-rpath 
  --enable-inline-optimization 
  --with-bz2 
  --with-zlib 
  --enable-sockets 
  --enable-sysvsem 
  --enable-sysvshm 
  --enable-pcntl 
  --enable-mbregex 
  --enable-exif 
  --enable-bcmath 
  --with-mhash 
  --enable-zip 
  --with-pcre-regex 
  --with-mysql 
  --with-pdo-mysql 
  --with-mysqli 
  --with-png-dir=/usr 
  --enable-gd-native-ttf 
  --with-openssl 
  --with-fpm-user=nginx 
  --with-fpm-group=nginx 
  --with-libdir=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu 
  --enable-ftp 
  --with-imap 
  --with-imap-ssl 
  --with-kerberos 
  --with-gettext 
  --with-gd 
  --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/lib/ 
  --enable-fpm`

#### The error

```
/bin/bash /opt/source/php-src/libtool --silent --preserve-dup-deps --mode=compile cc  -Iext/standard/ -I/opt/source/php-src/ext/standard/ -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/opt/source/php-src/include -I/opt/source/php-src/main -I/opt/source/php-src -I/opt/source/php-src/ext/date/lib -I/opt/source/php-src/ext/ereg/regex -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/c-client -I/opt/source/php-src/ext/mbstring/oniguruma -I/opt/source/php-src/ext/mbstring/libmbfl -I/opt/source/php-src/ext/mbstring/libmbfl/mbfl -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/opt/source/php-src/ext/sqlite3/libsqlite -I/opt/source/php-src/ext/zip/lib -I/opt/source/php-src/TSRM -I/opt/source/php-src/Zend    -I/usr/include -g -O2 -fvisibility=hidden  -c /opt/source/php-src/ext/standard/info.c -o ext/standard/info.lo 
/bin/bash /opt/source/php-src/libtool --silent --preserve-dup-deps --mode=compile cc  -Iext/tokenizer/ -I/opt/source/php-src/ext/tokenizer/ -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/opt/source/php-src/include -I/opt/source/php-src/main -I/opt/source/php-src -I/opt/source/php-src/ext/date/lib -I/opt/source/php-src/ext/ereg/regex -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/c-client -I/opt/source/php-src/ext/mbstring/oniguruma -I/opt/source/php-src/ext/mbstring/libmbfl -I/opt/source/php-src/ext/mbstring/libmbfl/mbfl -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/opt/source/php-src/ext/sqlite3/libsqlite -I/opt/source/php-src/ext/zip/lib -I/opt/source/php-src/TSRM -I/opt/source/php-src/Zend    -I/usr/include -g -O2 -fvisibility=hidden  -c /opt/source/php-src/ext/tokenizer/tokenizer.c -o ext/tokenizer/tokenizer.lo 
/bin/bash /opt/source/php-src/libtool --silent --preserve-dup-deps --mode=compile cc  -Iext/tokenizer/ -I/opt/source/php-src/ext/tokenizer/ -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/opt/source/php-src/include -I/opt/source/php-src/main -I/opt/source/php-src -I/opt/source/php-src/ext/date/lib -I/opt/source/php-src/ext/ereg/regex -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/c-client -I/opt/source/php-src/ext/mbstring/oniguruma -I/opt/source/php-src/ext/mbstring/libmbfl -I/opt/source/php-src/ext/mbstring/libmbfl/mbfl -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/opt/source/php-src/ext/sqlite3/libsqlite -I/opt/source/php-src/ext/zip/lib -I/opt/source/php-src/TSRM -I/opt/source/php-src/Zend    -I/usr/include -g -O2 -fvisibility=hidden  -c /opt/source/php-src/ext/tokenizer/tokenizer_data.c -o ext/tokenizer/tokenizer_data.lo 
In file included from /opt/source/php-src/main/php.h:406:0,
                 from /opt/source/php-src/ext/tokenizer/tokenizer_data.c:26:
/opt/source/php-src/ext/tokenizer/tokenizer_data.c: In function ‘tokenizer_register_constants’:
/opt/source/php-src/ext/tokenizer/tokenizer_data.c:89:40: error: ‘T_CHARACTER’ undeclared (first use in this function)
  REGISTER_LONG_CONSTANT("T_CHARACTER", T_CHARACTER, CONST_CS | CONST_PERSISTENT);
                                        ^
/opt/source/php-src/Zend/zend_constants.h:43:103: note: in definition of macro ‘REGISTER_LONG_CONSTANT’
 #define REGISTER_LONG_CONSTANT(name, lval, flags)  zend_register_long_constant((name), sizeof(name), (lval), (flags), module_number TSRMLS_CC)
                                                                                                       ^
/opt/source/php-src/ext/tokenizer/tokenizer_data.c:89:40: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
  REGISTER_LONG_CONSTANT("T_CHARACTER", T_CHARACTER, CONST_CS | CONST_PERSISTENT);
                                        ^
/opt/source/php-src/Zend/zend_constants.h:43:103: note: in definition of macro ‘REGISTER_LONG_CONSTANT’
 #define REGISTER_LONG_CONSTANT(name, lval, flags)  zend_register_long_constant((name), sizeof(name), (lval), (flags), module_number TSRMLS_CC)
                                                                                                       ^
/opt/source/php-src/ext/tokenizer/tokenizer_data.c:90:44: error: ‘T_BAD_CHARACTER’ undeclared (first use in this function)
  REGISTER_LONG_CONSTANT("T_BAD_CHARACTER", T_BAD_CHARACTER, CONST_CS | CONST_PERSISTENT);
                                            ^
/opt/source/php-src/Zend/zend_constants.h:43:103: note: in definition of macro ‘REGISTER_LONG_CONSTANT’
 #define REGISTER_LONG_CONSTANT(name, lval, flags)  zend_register_long_constant((name), sizeof(name), (lval), (flags), module_number TSRMLS_CC)
                                                                                                       ^
/opt/source/php-src/ext/tokenizer/tokenizer_data.c: In function ‘get_token_type_name’:
/opt/source/php-src/ext/tokenizer/tokenizer_data.c:228:8: error: ‘T_CHARACTER’ undeclared (first use in this function)
   case T_CHARACTER: return "T_CHARACTER";
        ^
/opt/source/php-src/ext/tokenizer/tokenizer_data.c:229:8: error: ‘T_BAD_CHARACTER’ undeclared (first use in this function)
   case T_BAD_CHARACTER: return "T_BAD_CHARACTER";
        ^
make: *** [ext/tokenizer/tokenizer_data.lo] Error 1
root@patrick:/opt/source/php-src#
```

#### Setup

- Ubuntu 14.04.3 x64
- 8gb RAM
- Intel i5

---

If you need more information, tell me before down vote.

Thanks.

Comment: Get the same on a Fedora 25 just today with latest git ``PHP-5.6``. Seems to be broken somehow.

Comment: I'm sure you're aware but just in case, ondrej has a ppa that will let you install the packages side by side.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this same error attempting to compile PHP `5.6.30` on Ubuntu 14 and decided to follow up some more. It turned out I was using an unsupported version of GNU Bison. Ubuntu 14.04 provides Bison version `3.x.x`. It turns out that PHP5 supports only Bison 2.4 and above (but not greater-than or equal-to `3.x.x`). I haven't found an exact source that backs up this claim. However I believe my conclusion is reasonable based on trial and error.

To compile PHP 5.6 on Ubuntu 14.04, I downloaded Bison 2.5 from [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bison/1:2.5.dfsg-2.1). Find the architecture of your machine and download the corresponding `.deb` archive. Extract the contents of the package's data section under some directory like so:

```
$ ar x bison_2.5.dfsg-2.1_ARCH.deb
$ tar xf data.tar.gz
```

Now you need to point the configure script to use that version of Bison when it configures the build. To do this, set the `PATH` variable to first point at the location of the custom Bison binary (note: The data archive expands to `./usr/bin/bison` under the extraction directory):

```
$ PATH=/path/to/extraction/usr/bin:$PATH ./configure ...
```

You should see something like the following in the output:

```
checking for bison... bison -y
checking for bison version... 2.5 (ok)
```

Now try `make`. If the results are like mine it should build properly.

Interestingly, I've built PHP `7.0.9` before using Bison 3 and it worked fine. I'm inclined to think that this is only a limitation for PHP 5 builds.